Is corona discharge immediately harmful in and of itself?
I am interested in knowing whether the corona discharge effect has any immediate harmful impact on the human body. I am not interested in knowing the effects of long-term exposure, relating to things like ozone production, etc. For discussion's sake, assume 10 seconds of exposure. Consider the setup below:

As you can see, the field strength is 100kV/cm, more than enough to ionize air and cause corona under normal conditions. However the wires are coated in a layer of insulation (the thickness of which is neglicible) capable of withstanding at least 100kV that prevents any arcs from occuring. Corona discharge, most of the time is near room temperature so I don't believe temperature is a concern.
My question, which aims to understand the nature of corona discharge, is: would a person survive touching the corona that is between the two high voltage electrodes?

I've had a corona discharge drill a microscopic hole in my finger ... it was only about 10 kV though ... touched the HV section on the back of a crt TV without looking ... my hand was grounded at the wrist by contact with the chassis ... I did not pull away right away, because I did not feel anything at first, but it hurt afterward ... smelled like burning hair

What are you planning to stick  in that narrow 10mm gap? Your pinkie or your tongue is conductive so some current will go through it. You also better hope there are no pinholes in that thin insulation. "Survive" is a low bar. You would survive with anything that can be stuck in a 10mm gap vaporized and cauterized.

These kinds of questions always make me uncomfortable.  People playing with 100 kV potentials (or equally dangerous things) shouldn't be asking random people on the internet about safety related issues. (Not that there's bad advice given here, just that you should really do the research and be an expert in these things before playing with them.)

Why ask here? This isn't an electronics question, in my opinion. And you can look up a variety of papers on the topic. Just search the literature. A quick hit I got on NCBI tells me that there are a variety of systems with varying responses. For example, visual phosphenes are different from the Aplysia pacemaker neurons that synchronize with each other and drive the heart. Add hormonal impacts and you already have three different systems with three differing response, already. I was quickly able to find that under 200 kV/m is one thing, but over that figure is another thing.

(You are way, way over 200 kV/m.) I focused on acute and not chronic responses and looked only for ELF studies, excluding RF. Since your question is short-term, use the word acute in your searches. That said, I don't know how to turn this into an electronics question. But if you were to try and find a way, then I'd expect you to have already looked up relevant research, studied the topic thoroughly, and to have provided us with a summary of what you found out so that you can provide a carefully crafted context for the question.

This is an ill-formed question:

Air breakdown is approx. 30 kV/cm.  You won't get corona discharge but arcing here.

The insulation thickness is "negligible" yet "withstands 100kV".  Typical good insulators are on the order of 100kV/cm breakdown field strength (with some particular materials pushing into the 10MV/cm range, e.g. defect-free mica).  Evidently these layers will be at least some mm thick, a sizable percentage of the total gap.

Corona discharge is an ongoing, dynamic process.  It is not an object that is summoned and persists thereafter.  In particular, your scenario, starting from zero applied voltage, would exhibit a few sparks, some hissing (actual corona), then eventually settle out -- assuming we afford a few mm layer of mica insulating the electrodes around the 1cm air gap.  The sparks are termed partial discharge, as it's not a continuous spark but merely delivers enough charge to polarize the dielectric(s).  (The measurement of PD is important for assessing the quality of insulation in high-voltage components.)
Another term is dielectric barrier discharge, usually an AC process (the dielectrics act like coupling capacitors, carrying current into the airspace between), but it still works if we're only going through one half-cycle of it.  It just only works the one time...

Because corona is a dynamic process, because it depends on electric field strength in air, and because a finger is conductive, introducing a finger doesn't "touch" anything; at best, some partial discharge sparks to the finger, from the surfaces, depositing a little more charge into them.
This is a familiar experience for the generation that grew up with CRT televisions and computer monitors: when the tube starts up, a high voltage (typically 10-30kV) is present on the inner surface of the glass face.  The dielectric constant of glass is high, so the outer surface is immediately charged to the same voltage, and partial breakdown ensues.  Minute sparks jump along the surface, reaching the ground strap at the edge of the display.  Eventually this settles down, field strength falling below breakdown; a residual charge remains, which a curious kid might sweep up with their hand, with satisfying crackle, and then discharge to -- let's say, an annoying sibling standing nearby?

If we replace the static voltage with AC, the process simply repeats on each swing; field stabilizes quickly (sparks themselves jump in the sub-ns regime, and material and air relaxation time constants are in the µs to ms) so it's basically that times however many cycles per second it runs at.  (Thus a sub-point of the ill-formation: for a single voltage application, it doesn't much matter if we count 10ms or 10s, it's the same charge applied to the finger regardless.)
At high enough frequency, the air can remain ionized between cycles, and a sort of quasi-glow discharge results; this will quickly heat up the insulators, accelerating breakdown until a direct arc flows between electrodes.  (Needless to say, any finger present, will be heated up rapidly, in addition to ionization and ozone damage to, and into, the skin.)

You will have trouble finding volunteers for this experiment; or at least, I sincerely hope so.  I personally would not put any part of my body within a meter of such voltages, no matter how well insulated.  (I might make an exception for charge and current limited sources, a small Van de Graaff generator perhaps, but if we're stipulating voltage, this isn't relevant.)  100kV (static) is the realm of high-energy xray machines and low-energy physics apparatus.  Even a small amount of metal, charged to such voltages, packs an impressive wallop.


